# Differences between View create with xml - View create with code

Tags: java, android, android-layout

There is a difference when I'm trying to add programmatically RelativeLayout and when I use directly xml view.

If I copy paste several RelativeLayout in container_tabs it works..

And when I try to inflate a relativeLayout file (exactly same as into container_tabs) the result is different and it doesn't works.

**How I fill my view programmatically**

```
    @BindView(R.id.container_tabs)
    protected LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainerTabs;

    private List<CustomBookingTab> mBookingTabsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private void initCustomButtonsTabs() {
       mBookingTabsList.add(new CustomBookingTab(this, EnumBookingTab.BOOKING_TAB_CALENDAR, R.drawable.ic_calendar_white));
       mBookingTabsList.add(new CustomBookingTab(this, EnumBookingTab.BOOKING_TAB_TIME, R.drawable.ic_clock));


       for (int i = 0; i < mBookingTabsList.size(); i++) {
            mLinearLayoutContainerTabs.addView(mBookingTabsList.get(i).getRelativeLayoutBookingTab(), i);
       }
    }
```

**How I inflate my view from a xml file (CustomBookingTab constructor)**

```
mRelativeLayoutBookingTab = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_tab, null);
```

**Main view**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-29dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <!-- Tab item -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="70dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/circle_blue_button_border_white"
                            android:padding="21dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_white"
                            android:text="Button"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Is there a good way to do that? What is wrong?

Comment: Where is `mLinearLayoutContainerTabs` being created? Could you provide more code?

Comment: I added `mLinearLayoutContainerTabs`. it's just a simple activity

Answer (score 0):

There are some difference to add view from XML and by inflating view anatomically.

but In case of Relative Layout when you are preparing XML there are so many relative properties are used to set different views together into XML .

And When we are adding views dynamically using Relative Layout we should use option of ADDRULE like bellow :

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout  = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button button1 = new Button(this);
        button1.setId(1);
        Button button2 = new Button(this);
        button2.setId(2);
        relativeLayout.addView(button1);
        relativeLayout.addView(button2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button1.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, button2.getId());
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, button2.getId());
```

Almost all Relative Layout properties you can dynamically through  AddRull .